# Surjective isometry $F:\bar{S}\to \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ given by an ortonormal system on a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis

I have an ortonormal system $\{e_j\}_{j \in \mathbb Z}$ in a Hilbert space. Let $S= \operatorname{span}\{e_j\}_{j \in \mathbb Z}$ and $F: v \to \{\left\langle v,e_j\right\rangle \} \in \ell^2(\mathbb Z), v \in H$. Then $F|_{\bar{S}}$ is a surjective isometry from $\bar{S}$ to $\ell^2(Z)$.
But is it linear?

Let $u,v\in H \quad F(u+v)=\{<u+v,e_j>\}=\{<u,e_j>\}+\{<v,e_j>\}=F(u)+F(v)$?

It's right?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What is $F$?　The domain of $F$ should not be $v$. Do you mean $F:H\rightarrow l^2(\mathbb{Z})$ defined by $F(v)=\cdots$ ?

Comment: Yes, but the prof write the function like this